# How to export and import Nexus repositories? (without a Pro account)

Tags: repository, backup, nexus3

I was wondering if it is possible to export and import my nexus-repositories without using the task which sonartype provides to its pro-users. This way it would be possible to backup and restore one specific repository.

Answer (score 1):

I used [this script](https://github.com/mr-anderson86/nexus3-repository-export) (had to [work out some kinks](https://github.com/mr-anderson86/nexus3-repository-export/compare/master...lwiechec:nexus3-repository-export:master)) to download the artifacts from Nexus3.

The author also describes [Nexus import scripts](https://github.com/sonatype-nexus-community/nexus-repository-import-scripts) that can be used to upload the artifacts to another repository.